# Problem in accepting emulator command in the cmd

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

I am using emulator command and getting this error

'emulator' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

but as I am using ADB command that works fine

I have declared Android_home and android_java variable but getting error

Answer (score 3):

Try by going to System properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables -> System variables -> Path -> Add a semicolon and add the path of the Emulator